# Cross-compiling ZSH statically

Tags: compilation, static-libraries, cross-compiling, zsh, static-linking

I want to cross-compile zsh for arm (an android device) but statically. I want the result to be a bunch of binaries that does not require a bunch of libs that android does not have. I don't care about the size of the binary.
I have compiled (statically) ncurses for android and I try to compile zsh:

```
ttouch zsh$ CFLAGS="-Wl,-static -static-libgcc -L/media/files/Lab/compilenv/ncurses-5.9/root/lib -lncurses" ./configure --host=arm-linux --disable-dynamic --disable-restricted-r --disable-gdbm --with-term-lib=ncurses --prefix=$(pwd)/root/
<everything ok>
ttouch zsh$ make -j16
<everything ok>
ttouch zsh$  readelf -d Src/zsh | grep NEEDED
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libncurses.so.5]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librt.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
```

so, how can I compile zsh statically?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm thinking of doing the same. I've got zsh and oh-my-zsh on everything from my rackspace hosts to my raspberry pi and would love to see them on my phone.

Comment: nope... but in a month or so I'll really start working on it again. I will make it work no katter what. Apart from static, we can alter linker to support LD_LIBRARY_PATH and compile it dinamically.

Comment: did you manage it?

Comment: nope but it has been 4 years since then. What problem do you face